# wp_next_scheduled returning a past timestamp

Tags: wp-cron

So, here is my entire code in wp_content/plugins/my_plugin/my_plugin.php :

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'comunity_mails_activation');
add_action('check_mails_to_send', 'do_this_daily');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'comunity_mails_deactivation'); 

function comunity_mails_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'check_mails_to_send');
}

function comunity_mails_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('check_mails_to_send');
}

function do_this_daily() {
    wp_mail("my@email.net", "Automated Email", "Hell yeah it works!");
}
```

When I do `echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s",wp_next_scheduled('check_mails_to_send'));` in the functions.php of my theme, it prints 13-02-2013 14:22:03

So I tried to do this :

```
do_action('ckeck_mails_to_send');
```

And my mail was sent. So I wonder, do I have to unschedule the task and schedule it again for the next day and compare the two timestamps and ... sounds silly...

I just don't understand why the mail has not been sent and why it's not scheduling it for the next day.

Thanks for reading/helping =D

Comment: Well, as I was working on an existing site which as maaaaany plugins already installed, I figured out that there was a `define(DISABLE_WP_CON,true);` somewhere in the code.

Sorry... ^_^'

Comment: No need to be sorry, this was super helpful! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as I was working on an existing site which as maaaaany plugins already installed, I figured out that there was a `define(DISABLE_WP_CRON,true);`

So when you seems to have the same problem than me. Do a research of `define(DISABLE_WP_CRON,true);` in your files.